# openlayers ol3 linestring getLength not returning expected value

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using getLength to retrieve the linestring length.

For the same segment:
1- when using google map measure tool, I get 228m
2- when using IGN geoportail measure tool, I get 228m
3- when I use e.feature.getGeometry().getLength() I get 330m

Here are the flat coordinates:
e.feature.getGeometry().getFlatCoordinates() :
[571382.4214041593, 5723486.068714521, 571593.8175605105, 5723741.65502785]

in 4326:
[5.132815622245775, 45.644023326845485, 5.134714626228319, 45.64562844964627]

When I check the coordinates position on either ol3 or google map, I get the same points. The difference must come from the calcul...

Did I miss something and I should not use the getLength method? Please give me some direction if you think this is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geometry.getLength()` returns the length in the map view projection, which is usually spherical mercator. Spherical mercator distances are stretched at a rate of `1/cos(latitude)`; in your example: `228/330 ~ cos(45.64)`.

To get the real spherical distance:

```
var geometry = feature.getGeometry();

alert (geometry.getLength());

// get points of geometry (for simplicity assume 2 points)
var coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();

// transform points from map projection (usually spherical mercator) to WGS84
var mapProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
var t1 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[0], mapProjection, 'EPSG:4326');
var t2 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[1], mapProjection, 'EPSG:4326');

// create sphere to measure on
var wgs84sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137); // one of WGS84 earth radius'

// get distance on sphere
var dist = wgs84sphere.haversineDistance(t1, t2);

alert (dist);
```

For even higher accuracy you have to measure on the WGS84 ellipsoid instead of the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, allthough if you are trying to get the length of a LinePoint with several positions it will only calculate between the first ones.

Here is a small addition on working with LinePoints with several positions:

```
var geometry = feature.getGeometry();


// get points of geometry (for simplicity assume 2 points)
var coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();

// transform points from map projection (usually spherical mercator) to WGS84
var mapProjection = map.getView().getProjection();

// create sphere to measure on
var wgs84sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137); // one of WGS84 earth radius'

var dist = 0;
//loop through all coordinates
for(var i = 0; i < coordinates.length -1; i++) {
    var t1 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[i], mapProjection, 'EPSG:4326');
    var t2 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[i+1], mapProjection, 'EPSG:4326');
    // get distance on sphere
    dist += wgs84sphere.haversineDistance(t1, t2);
}
alert(dist);
```